# Should I suggest someone delete an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

If there's an answer to a duplicate, which is quickly closed as such, would it be fair to ask the answerer to delete their answer if it adds nothing to the duplicate, nothing new? Or is it considered rude to ask someone to delete their upvoted answer? I'm under the impression that we should delete our answers if they add nothing to the duplicate regardless of upvotes or accepts. Would it be fair to ask someone to delete their answer?

Comment: If it's an exact duplicate, would downvote with an explanation of duplication not do the trick? I personally do not always care to see what was in the duplicate, after I already posted an answer

Comment: @Icepickle It's just the fact that these answers get fast upvotes, which in turn encourage the answerer *and* asker to further continue this behavior. SO is for building a knowledge base, and if we just continue answering the same questions, what's the point? The quality will slowly go down as the same questions just come time and time again.

Comment: I would see nothing bad in being asked to delete my answer, and if asked to do so, I would look into the question and answer on the duplicate one. If I would delete it really depends if imho I really didn't contribute with the new answer. So probably it's a good thing to ask, though I can assume people might be offended if you ask (eg, people just passing a certain privilige level might be annoyed)

Comment: @Icepickle I guess, but there was a particular example that got 4 instant upvotes and added nothing new, it had less info than the duplicate, and they were a high rep level. I wanted ask this question before taking action, but nobody, no matter the rep level, is above the rules.

Comment: How about we just delete the question (which also wipes out the answer)?

Comment: I am guessing this is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721838/why-does-this-code-produce-an-error-even-when-i-made-the-variable-to-long-dataty/44721856#comment76425905_44721856) in question? Please tell me to delete this comment, in case I am overstepping my bounds here

Comment: You're not violating any rules by asking, but you should expect only a tiny fraction to ever actually delete their answer (and lots to get mad at you anyway).  The kind of person that goes around posting low quality answers to common duplicates generally isn't the type to delete it when it gets upvotes (as they virtually always do).  Given this I'd consider posting such comments usually just a waste of time, unless you know the user and know they're one to be receptive to being pointed out that the question is already well answered elsewhere.

Comment: @Servy Okay, thanks for the advice. I expected a response of that nature anyways from comments telling to delete their answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver that would be optimal, but it's extremely hard to delete a duplicate with an answer of +5 if it's not blatantly a bad question.

Comment: @AndrewLi Really?  All it takes is 3 10K people to delete the Q unless it is highly voted (then it could take up to 10 votes).

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, duh! I was thinking about the *answer*, not the question. That would be the best option here.

Comment: Yeah, if the dupe is not needed (adds nothing new, no signposting) then we can just delete it.  Doesn't matter if there are answers or not or how they are scored.

Comment: More generally, SO really does very little in its searches to identify useful synonyms or alternative wording. I assume that would be a true feat for even the most advance modern AI, considering the variety of topics and technical terms here. I've answered questions before that I was certain would already have been asked, but the terms I chose to search just weren't fruitful. I've also stumbled upon questions that essentially had identical conceptual content and answers, but which question used very different terms and **contexts**. It would be unfortunate to delete such questions & answers.

Comment: @CPerkins I heard of a small company that tries to search resources such as SO this intelligently. [These are them](https://www.google.com). But seriously: using google instead of built-in SO search and appending `site:stackoverflow.com` works miracles.

Comment: If this is indeed about the question that @Icepickle mentioned, then... That question was closed and subsequently reopened by the answerer. I just voted to close again, because it looks like a very obvious duplicate to me and I don't understand why a gold badge holder would not close it as such, let alone reopen the question.

Comment: As an info, I also added the link to this meta post on the answer, so that the gold badger can give his version of events ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Why restrict your search to SO (if you're actually looking for the answer, and not, say, trying to find a duplicate to close the question as)?  If the top result is somewhere other than SO, don't you want to see it?

Comment: @Servy my remark was exactly in the context of hunting duplicates. Otherwise of course, just google it.

Answer (score 5):

I *have* asked answerers to delete their duplicate or outdated answers, pointing out they get a [Disciplined badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7612/150034).

Some did, most unfortunately didn't. I even got chastised by others.